# Xamarin iOS: how to dim status bar if there is Pop-up

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, popup, statusbar

I'm work on changing iOS status bar color and it's text color. The result appeared good except when a pop-up shown on screen. As shown as the image below, the status bar does not dimmed when a pop-up displayed on screen, it seems to stand out on the screen.

As I really not familiar with iPhone, does it usually work this way? Or is there any workaround to dim status bar if pop-up appeared?

**Note**: I am using iPhone X with iOS 12.1

**Pop-up Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<pages:BasePopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="WhiteLabel.Mobile.App.Pages.Popup.TransferPopUp"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:WhiteLabel.Mobile.App.Pages.Popup"
    xmlns:popups="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:Resources="clr-namespace:WhiteLabel.Mobile.App.Resources">

    <!--Animations use example-->
    <popups:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
          PositionIn="Center"
          PositionOut="Center"
          ScaleIn="1.2"
          ScaleOut="0.8"
          DurationIn="400"
          DurationOut="300"
          EasingIn="SinOut"
          EasingOut="SinIn"
          HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </popups:PopupPage.Animation>

    <!-- Content -->
    <StackLayout 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
           Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
           <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
             <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
              </Grid>

              <StackLayout >
                <Label 
                     Text="DELETE_POPUP_INFO"
                     HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                     VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>


                <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!-- Cancel button-->
                    <Button x:Name="CancelButton"
                            Command="{Binding TappedCloseCommand}"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Text="CANCEL" 
                            BorderWidth="1"
                            BorderRadius="0">
                        <Button.BorderRadius>
                            <!-- fixes a bug on android where border doesn't work without a radius. -->
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Int32">
                                <OnPlatform.Android>1</OnPlatform.Android>
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Button.BorderRadius>
                    </Button>

                    <!-- Delete button-->
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
                            Command="{Binding TappedDeleteCommand}"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Text="DELETE"  
                            WidthRequest="500"
                            BorderRadius="0">
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>

</pages:BasePopupPage>
```

[image]

Comment: I download the [demo](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) and test it just now. I found the default behavior of back black View is start from the status bar, can you share your code? You want the back black view overlap the status bar, right?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT, yes, exactly. I would like the black view overlap the status bar. And you want the code that showing pop-up?

Comment: Yes, just a sample code of pop-up and I can test it for you on my side.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT,  I have updated with sample code.

Comment: Ok, I will test it tomorrow and update you.

Answer (score 0):

I use your code and create a pop up page. It works as expected. I will show you the code I use and you can have a look at it.

Here is button event I use to show the pop-up:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new Page1());
}
```

And I did not add additional code in the pop up page:

```
public partial class Page1 : PopupPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The code in Xaml is the same as you and I use `Rg.Plugins.Popup` with version `1.1.5.188`.

I can share you the sample if you want.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]